# how to Execute a selected ComboBox in GUI using Java Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, combobox, execute

I want to execute a selected item in palette GUI using Java Netbeans. Recently, I can only execute the 'run' button without any select item. I intention to select one of items first, then execute the button.
Here is the code:

```
User user = status.getUser();
        Date dated = status.getCreatedAt();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Connection conne = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conne = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "");
            System.out.println(status);
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
            stmt = conne.prepareStatement("set names 'utf8'");
            stmt.execute();
            stmt = conne.prepareStatement("set character set utf8");
            stmt.execute();
            stmt = conne.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tweet(ID,date,name,statusLocation,text,source) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt.setInt(1, (int) status.getId());
            stmt.setString(2, getTimeStamp());
            stmt.setString(3, status.getUser().getScreenName());
            stmt.setString(4, user.getLocation());
            stmt.setString(5, status.getText());
            stmt.setString(6, status.getSource());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("this record inserted!");
            System.out.println("==================");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onStallWarning(StallWarning sw) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
};       
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
double lat1 = 121.300000d;
double long1 = 25.020000d;
double lat2 = 121.380000d;
double long2 = 25.030000d;
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
double[][] bb = {{lat1, long1}, {lat2, long2}};
fq.locations(bb);
twitterStream.filter(fq);}
```

And this is the interface:

[image]

I thanksful for any comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the combo-box.
2. Right-click for popup menu.
3. Choose Events -> Item -> Item State Changed in menu.
4. It will setup a function to be called when the item is selected.

Edit to something like this

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        String selected_item = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        switch(selected_item) {
        case "Japan":
            // do something when japan is selected.
            break;

        case "China":
            // do something when China is selected.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I put the value of item? for example I want to select 'Japan'

Comment: because I just add some codes to your comment, but I can execute it whatever item I select

Comment: because different item is different result I wish

Comment: I think you want to switch on the result of getSelectedItem() and do different things for the different items.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I want.. Oh I see your edit

Comment: it's works, but I want to activate the function of 'run' button. because with this way I can run by selecting one of item (don't need to click 'run' button)

Comment: Just call the same function that is called when the run button is pushed.

Comment: Got It! This question has been solved by WillShackleford! Thank you again and again! :)